# What is $\bigcup_{r\in(0,1)}[0,r]$?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Question: for any real number $r$, let $C_r$ be the closed interval $[0,r]$. Let $J$ be the open interval $(0,1)$. what is $\bigcup_{j\in J} C_j$? So far I have attempted a double inclusion proof to little avail.

Comment: $[0,1)$?​​​​​​​

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** Note that for every $j$, $C_j\subseteq[0,1)$, therefore the union is a subset of $[0,1)$. Moreover, since $j\in C_j$, it follows that $(0,1)$ is a subset of the union. This should allow you to conclude the wanted equality.